# jscrollpane inside prettyphoto lightbox - not working

Tags: jscrollpane, prettyphoto

I have implemented a prettyphoto lightbox for a inline-div which will require custom scrollbar for its lengthy content. So used jscrollpane to implement custom scroll.

They individually work in background but when the inline-div is called in prettyphoto lightbox the drag / scroll does not work.

Please help.

I have update the scrollpane, updated the prettyphoto, even used many lightbox and other scrolling js but no success.

Comment: You can check the issues at the following url
http://simplyfm.com/12016/test.html#!prettyPhoto

Also check the screenshot
http://simplyfm.com/12016/issue.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to figure out the same thing. I've gotten as far is might involve this http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/ajax_example.html and the prettyPhoto changepicturecallback function (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2010/09/28/tutorial-opening-custom-content-in-prettyphoto/), but haven't gotten the two to successfully work together.